# I can't add IPs to my database. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, ip

So what I want is to be able to add different IPs to my database. What I do is:

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE csgo_servers SET ips = ips + '$anip' + '|' WHERE id = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "IP Added!";
}
```

I want to have different IPs in a Longtext column like that: `32.12.53.12|42.12.41.2|42.1.6.3.7`. The problem is when I do it it only adds the first let's say 32.12 of the IP and without the |. Any help?

Comment: You should look into normalising your database in the first place; character separated values in a single cell is terrible abuse of an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

**Structure of your table**
Like it was mentioned in the comments, having character-separated values in a database like that (in your case, the separator is `|`), is a **bad idea**. You should normalize your database - have more rows instead of doing that. It'll be way easier to work with!

**Why this won't work as it is**
MySQL can't add strings together with `+` (like you do in JavaScript). That's telling MySQL that you want to do *mathematics* (adding integers, e.g `1+1`). That means that you're silently converting to integers, which is why you're only seeing the first part of the IP (the first part before the period `.` is an integer, the rest is turnicated).

**Solution**
You can use the `CONCAT()` function to achieve what you want - although like mentioned above, ***I strongly advise against this structure***, this will add the last IP with a separator `|`.

With also adding the new IP with a bounded placeholder (like you bind the ID), the new code would look like this. You should always bind *every* variable going into the query, otherwise it's a little pointless.

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE csgo_servers SET ips = CONCAT(ips, '|', ?) WHERE id = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $anip, $id);
    if ($stmt->execute())
        echo "IP Added!";
    $stmt->close();
}
```

- [MySQL on `CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)